# Using Windows DNS Server with AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, windows-server-2016, amazon-lightsail

I am newly using AWS and I am using first time AWS lightsail. I am in trouble about DNS Server Managing;

- I get a static ip but I can't see this static ip in IIS Bindings setting.
- I installed DNS Server feature from add roles and features widzard.
- I added a **Forward Lookup Zone** for my site, When I add ns records I can't use public(static ip) so I used private Ip.

I am using many vps providers (Vultr, Google etc.) but I am living first time problem like this.

I reach the site from public(static) ip but I can't reach from domain and I can't reach ns record.

What is I missed about that?

Answer (score 0):

I understood AWS operation type so;

- I am using private/internal ip for IIS bindings and DNS records, AWS automatically mask it with public/static ip.
- I was living DNS reach problem and I solved the DNS reach problem with opening DNS ports from network security area.

  So I missed open the DNS ports from AWS lightsail firewall.

Comment: Hello, can you please provide more information? I am trying to achieve the same thing here. THanks.

Comment: You can add new port from Networking tab under lightsail instance.